# jquery-ui modal dialog background

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Trying to change the background of a jquery-ui modal dialog as it is transparent but it's not working. As per jquery-ui documentation what I tried is:

```
.ui-dialog, {
    background: black; 
}

.ui-dialog-content {
    background: black; 
}
```

in my main CSS file but with no success.

Comment: Load order of css files? The rest of your custom css file? We need more code than the provided

Comment: remove the `,` in your first line by the way.  `.ui-dialog,` should just be `.ui-dialog{`. I assume that was just quick formatting for the question.

Comment: Damn!!! Guess too many hours in front of the computer.... Can you believe I did not really see that!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `,` in your first line. `.ui-dialog,{` should just be `.ui-dialog{`